# Where does Durandal router set page title

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am using Durandal for a very simple website.  In all of my browser tabs the page title is coming up with "undefined|" appended to the front of the application's title.  Where is Durandal getting and setting that value?

pthalacker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately Durandal's router plugin is setting the document.title.

https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/durandal/plugins/router.js#L254

```
onNavigationComplete: function (routeInfo, params, module) {
    if (app.title) {
        document.title = routeInfo.caption + " | " + app.title;
    } else {
        document.title = routeInfo.caption;
    }
},...
```

Typically Durandal is able to construct a missing caption propterty on the route object, so maybe there's something different in the way the routes are set up.

https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/samples/shell.js#L6

```
router.map([

   { url: 'hello', moduleId: 'samples/hello/index', name: 'Hello World', visible: true },
   { url: 'hello/:name', moduleId: 'samples/hello/index', name: 'Examples' },...
]);
```

Comment: I am using autoMap.  Do I need to manually specify all my routes to give them captions?

Comment: Looks like there was an issue with `mapAuto` a few month ago. https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/pull/97. I'd suggest downloading  the 1.2 files from http://durandaljs.com/pages/downloads/ as the router sub systems is under heavy rework at github at the momnent.

Comment: I just uninstalled and reinstalled durandal and the router.  Package manager says I have 1.2.0.  Still have undefined in the routeInfo.caption.  Where is the routeInfo object created?

Comment: I'd suggest that you build the router object by using router.map([...]) as recommended by http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router/. Otherwise you've to manually apply the patches in the PR above.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the page title when the viewmodel gets activated:

```
activate: function (params) {

    // Setting page title
    params.routeInfo.caption = "My Page Title";

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Replacing page titles in Durandal 2.1.0

#### (if you want to the page title to be something distinct from the last level of the route)

Slight modification to RainerAtSpirit's answer: Specify 'title' in the route instead of 'name'.

```
router.map([
   { url: 'hello', moduleId: 'samples/hello/index', title: 'Hello World', visible: true },
   { url: 'hello/:name', moduleId: 'samples/hello/index', title: 'Examples' },...
]);
```