# Durandal multilingual app, page/module title as an observable, changing document.title dynamically

Tags: javascript, router, durandal

I am working on localizing my durandal application. I have already chosen an approach - I am sharing a module across all my pages containing all the strings that any view may have.

In my shell I am defining

```
router.map([
    { route: ['', 'search'], title: i18n.search, moduleId: 'viewmodels/search/index', nav: true },
    { route: "employees", title: i18n.employeesList, moduleId: "viewmodels/employees/index", nav: false },
    { route: "details/:id", title: i18n.details, moduleId: "viewmodels/details/index", nav: false }
    // ...
]);
```

where the `i18n` properties are ko.observables containing strings like

```
i18n = {
    search: ko.observable("search"),
    employeesList: ko.observable("employeesList"),
    details: ko.observable("Details")
}
```

This works fine printing my navigation bar with

```
<ul class = "nav navbar-nav" data-bind = "foreach: router.navigationModel">
    <li data-bind = "css: { active: isActive }">
        <a data-bind = "attr: { href: hash }, text: title"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

however when it comes to having the document title changed, it does not work.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846082/where-does-durandal-router-set-page-title) I found something about durandal setting the document.title, unfortunately the answer suggests that to change the title durandal creates some other properties (that seem to be based on my `title` module object declaration property) and probably does not assume that the `title` might be something other than a string.

*Is there a way to override some method that durandal uses to change the document.title or any other way to make it change document.title when navigating?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the steps outlined in [Durandal.js 2.0 Set document title within activate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714213/durandal-js-2-0-set-document-title-within-activate-method).

You'd need to overwrite `router.updateDocumentTitle` in main.js|shell.js so that it takes into account that `config.title` is an observable.

Something along the following should get you started.

```
router.updateDocumentTitle = function(instance, instruction) {
    if (instruction.config.title) {
        if (app.title) {
            document.title = ko.unwrap(instruction.config.title) + " | " + app.title;
        } else {
            document.title = ko.unwrap(instruction.config.title);
        }
    } else if (app.title) {
        document.title = app.title;
    }
};
```

**Update:** Based on comment.

In addition to the modification above if the title should change immediately then there's some more work required.

Reason is that router doesn't know about language switching. Pub/sub is most probably the right way for the implementation. Consider setting up an event e.g using `app.on` that changes the document.title. `router.activeInstruction()` will provide access to the config object. Trigger the event whenever somebody is switching in whatever view model.

Comment: True, this worked. It still lacks the ability to refresh the title right on switching language, yet it is not that necessary. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This might come a little late, but I'd like to add my solution too :-)
I am using observables which change the text of my variables on demand.
When setting the routes and their options like this:

```
var routes = [{ route: '', title: 'Welcome', moduleId: 'viewmodels/welcome', nav: true, title: 
    ko.computed(function () { return activeTranslation.welcome() }) 
}];
```

my activeTranslation looks something like this:

```
var activeTranslation = {
    welcome: ko.observable()
}
```

Now when changing the language I just have to loop through my language object containing the same variables and their respective translation and apply them to the observable.

```
var dutch = { welcome: "Welkom" };

function loadLanguage (lang) {
    for (var key in languages[lang]) {
        activeTranslation[key](languages[lang][key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that work with `title` properties as `ko.computed()` observables? Shame I didn't come to that by myself because this seems to be a well-mannered solution to my case. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @patryk: Not your fault, just a case of extremely bad timing. I sent them a patch for this *exactly one day* after you asked your question here (unknowingly) and they [merged it](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/pull/343) in February '14.  You couldn't have seen it.

Comment: Even though this question got old, thank you for the information. I haven't been using neither durandal nor knockout for a while now but still thanks @tne !